# Java or Dot Net for server side Flash support

Tags: java, .net, flash

We are building a Flash application for client use but will need to do server side processing of images. All our expertise and application code is in Java, but I've been told Dot Net has better Flash support. This is general but we will be modifying large (up to 50MB) image files. The idea is that what we could do in Flash should be duplicated, automated and extended on the server side.

Comment: Why not PHP, Ruby, or any other server-side language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard before that **.Net** server technology has better Flash support than **Java**. In fact, [RED5](http://www.red5.org/) (an open source Media server for Flash) is implemented in Java.

As for capabilities, Both **.Net** and **Java** will be more than capable of duplicate and extend the same image processing done in Flash, and both have libraries and services that support [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) in case you require it.

Flash is pretty much server-agnostic anyways, so unless you get more specific reasons I think you should go with whichever language you are more comfortable with (which seems to be **Java**)